# Importing files from sibling directory

Tags: python, unit-testing, import, python-import, flask-testing

I need to run unit tests for my Flask app. In my test config file, I need to import the flask `create_app` function from a sibling directory to initialize the test app. I cannot figure it out without getting import errors.

I have tried putting `__init__.py` on virtually every folder without success. I have read that editing the sys path is not recommended so I would like a solution without.

**Folder Structure**

```
root/
----__init__.py
----server/
--------__init__.py
--------database.py
----tests/
--------__init__.py
--------config.py
```

**config.py**

```
from server import create_app
from server.database import db
```

Raises this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/config.py", line 2, in <module>
    from server import create_app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'server'
```

and:

```
from ..server import create_app
from ..server.database import db
```

Raises this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/config.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..server import create_app
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Can someone explain why it doesn't work and how python `import`s work in general? I have never been able to figure them out.

Comment: Thanks but why is installing it necessary? Why can't you just import packages normally through import statements like in JS for example?

Comment: Because that's just not how Python import system works.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an import statement to work correctly, names must be resolved in `sys.path` somehow. Creating a correct package structure and installing the package is usually the best way to get the names visible in `sys.path`.

1. Remove `root/__init__.py` and `tests/__init__.py`
2. Correct your import statements:

```py
from ..server import create_app  # no
from server import create_app  # yes
```

3. Add `root/setup.py` with contents as described in [setuptools basic guide](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#basic-use).
4. Create/activate virtualenv (usually in `root/.venv/` subdir, but doesn't really matter where)
5. From the project root, i.e. the directory containing `setup.py`, install your package:

```sh
pip install --editable .
```